# Is there a way to sideload APKs on a clover production device?

Tags: usb-debugging, clover-payment

We have an app that I developed is specific to our organization. We *could* put it through the Clover App Market, go through the approval process, etc..., but it would be basically useless for merchants that aren't us. What I'd like to do is load it manually onto our production devices (I've already tested it fairly thoroughly via an emulator and Clover devkit, so I'm not incredibly worried about bugs, although they are probably still there...)

It appears that there isn't a way to enable USB debugging (so I can sideload with adb) on production devices (attempting to enable USB debugging gives me a message stating that it can't be done on that device). I'm wondering if there is a way to either force-enable USB debugging via some type of setting that I can get into from a debug-only mode during boot, or if there might be another way I can get my app onto my devices?

Comment: One thing I have tried is setting up a web server to serve the APK directly, and then download it from the clover web browser. I think I have the nginx headers set up incorrectly, though, because the APK gets renamed by the browser to "appbin" instead of "app.apk". Other apks, such as Signal, download from the web, don't have this issue (although they don't install because they weren't made with the Clover SDK).